# How do I match version of python version between jupyter notebook and terminal? 3.6.5 to 3.7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I face the following errors on jupyter notebook which I believe is due to because of multiple versions of python on my laptop, I am trying import xgboost

`from xgboost import XGBClassifier`

I get the following error,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-4-3728958e329a> in <module>
     15 from sklearn.svm import SVC
     16 from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
---> 17 from xgboost import XGBClassifier

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

and I also get the following warnings when I run the `kfold` selection,

```
# evaluate each model in turn
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(
        model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:459: FutureWarning: Default multi_class will be changed to 'auto' in 0.22. Specify the multi_class option to silence this warning.
  "this warning.", FutureWarning)
```

I checked the versions of python on my terminal and jupyter notebook, I see that jupyter notebook has 3.6.5 version and terminal has 3.7 version.

Not sure if this is what causing the issue.

[image]

[image]

jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)
3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/shafeeqrahaman/.ipython']
```

This issue is not just with `xgboost` package but happens when I try to import keras as well

Comment: If you are installing you packages using pip, you can do pip3.6 install xgboost, so the package gets installed in the Jupyter notebook version.

Comment: how can I upgrade notebook to 3.7

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install Jupyter for Python 3.7. As you can see when you run `python3` in the console it comes up with Python 3.7 so that's the command you want to be using.

**Installing Jupyter** 
[Here is the documentation for reference.](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
According to the documentation you simply just run:

```
python3 -m pip --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

**Running Jupyter on Python 3.7** 
`python3 -m pip install jupyter` 
Will run Jupyter, but specifically on `python3`, which is bound to Python 3.7 for you.

*This is how I remember doing it but I haven't tested it right now so if something has changed this may not work.

Comment: I followed the commands but still on the jupyter notebook it says 3.6.5, import sys
print(sys.base_prefix)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6

Comment: import sys
print(sys.version)
3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55)

Comment: if you have both python 3.6 and python 3.7 installed, the version that `python3` invokes will depend on your specific configuration.  Since `python3` points to either the `python3.6` or `python3.7` executable, you may need to specify `python3.7 -m pip install` on such a system to guarantee the 3.7 interpreter is invoked.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I tried that but the python version on the jupyter notebook points to 3.6.5, I would like to know what can I do to make python in jupyter notebook point to 3.7.0

Comment: import sys
print(sys.version)
3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]